# Shibboleth SP3 MetadataGenerator md:ContactPerson

Tags: xml, shibboleth, service-provider

I want a md:ContactPerson to be included in the Metadata that’s generated from my.host.name/shibboleth.sso/Metadata. But I’m having a problem with the handler Metadatagenerator in shibboleth2.xml and including the md:ContactPerson.

When I’m trying to include md:ContactPerson the Shibboleth Daemon (Default) service stops working and the logger says it’s a XML error(s) during parsing.

This is my code in shibboleth2.xml file.

```
<Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="true">
    <md:ContactPerson contactType="support">
        <md:GivenName>support person name</md:GivenName>
        <md:SurName>testSurName</md:SurName>
        <md:EmailAddress>Testtest@example.org</md:EmailAddress>
    </md:ContactPerson>
    <md:ContactPerson contactType="technical">
        <md:GivenName>tech name</md:GivenName>
        <md:SurName>tech name 2</md:SurName>
        <md:EmailAddress>techguy@example.org</md:EmailAddress>
    </md:ContactPerson>
</Handler>
```

I’m using the SP3 version 3.0.2.0 of shibboleth.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I deleted my first answer as I wasn't aware you could even do this, and that feed isn't really intended for production use. However, I would suggest that you might have a problem with your XML syntax somewhere else... on my 3.0.2 SP I copied you generator config exactly and do not get an XML error during parsing. Perhaps you just have a typo somewhere else in the file?

Comment: Hi Kellen! If I remove the md:ContactPerson code the XML syntax  works. So, I’m not sure what’s the problem with my xml file... Will try and reinstall shibboleth and see if that works. Thx for letting me know that it’s not the md:ContacPerson part that’s wrong.

Comment: No problem. I went ahead and just tested this on my IIS/Windows server as well... directly copied the above handler from Stack Overflow and it built just fine, and loaded the metadata, and I was able to authenticate. I wonder if there's a special character or something of that effect that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The exact error you where getting was:

> ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : fatal error on line 45, column 41, message: prefix 'md' can not be resolved to namespace URI

My solution to this problem was to define following SPConfig attributes:

```xml
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    clockSkew="180">
  ....
  <ApplicationDefaults ...>
    ...
    <Sessions ...>
      <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false">
      <md:ContactPerson contactType="support">
      <md:GivenName>XXXXXXXX</md:GivenName>
      <md:SurName>YYYYYYYYY</md:SurName>
      <md:EmailAddress>x@y.z</md:EmailAddress>
      </md:ContactPerson>
      </Handler>
    </Sessions>
  </ApplicationDefaults>
</SPConfig>
```